# Unable to create instance in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a model named User which looks like following:

```
export class User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  email_verified:any;
  phone_verified:any;
  created:string;
  cnic:any;
  avatar:any
}
```

I have imported this User in my service and I am trying to create a user  like following:

```
let user:User;
 user.name='xyz';
      user.email=res.email;
      user.cnic=res.user.cnic;
      user.phone=res.user.phone;
      user.created='1/2/2017';
      user.avatar='';
      user.email_verified=true;
```

But it says that user is undefined! Cannot set property name of undefined.
Can someone guide me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
let user:User;
```

should be

```
let user = new User();
```

Comment: what is difference between two?

Comment: The former declares a variable of type `User` so that you can later assign a `User` instance to it. The later declares a variable and assigns a new `User` instance to it.

Answer (score 0):

Classes have to be instantiated with `new`.

Try

```
let user = new User();
```

And then assign its members.

The compiler will infer that `user` is of type `User`, so you don't need a type specifier.